# i don't want my form to refresh after i submit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i don't want my form to refresh after i submit because the link.innerHTML = "localhost/leads/lead.php?param="+address needs to be on the form after i submit Please help.

```
enter code here
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
                var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
                 var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                   var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
                      var position = document.getElementById('position').value;
                         var company = document.getElementById('company').value;
                           var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
                           var link = document.getElementById('link');
enter code here
$.ajax({
                    url: "scripts/index.php",
                    data: {propertyname: name, propertyaddress: address, propertyemail: email, propertyphone: phone, propertyposition: position, propertycompany: company,  propertymessage: message}
                });


                   link.innerHTML = "localhost/leads/lead.php?param="+address; 
            });
        });


    </script>
enter code here
 <div class="container mt-2">  
       <div class= "row">
       <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
          <div class="card card-body">
           <h1> Add Properties</h1> 
           <h2> </h2>

enter code here
<form  id="form">
         <div class= "form-group">
         <input type="text" placeholder=" Your Name" id="name" name="name" class = "form-control " required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$" /> <br>
         <div class= "form-group">
         <input type="url" placeholder="http://example.com" id="address" name="address" class ="form-control" pattern= "http?://.+" required/>  <br>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required pattern="[a-z0-9_%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"><br>
         <div class= "form-group">
enter code here
```

enter code here

```
        </div>

    </form>


         <div id="link"></div>




</body>
```

i just the form to submit without refreshing it please help because i want to use that link for another form thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the event parameter from the submit even listener i.e.

```
on.('submit', (e)=>{ 

e.preventDefault(); 
//Your code here

});
```

Comment: Your the best it works thank you very much God bless :)

Comment: I'm glad it did please mark the answer as correct! Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behavior of the event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        var position = document.getElementById('position').value;
        var company = document.getElementById('company').value;
        var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
        var link = document.getElementById('link');

        $.ajax({
            url: "scripts/index.php",
            data: {
                propertyname: name,
                propertyaddress: address,
                propertyemail: email,
                propertyphone: phone,
                propertyposition: position,
                propertycompany: company,
                propertymessage: message
            }
        });


        link.innerHTML = "localhost/leads/lead.php?param=" + address;
    });
});
```